# Error installing anchor-cli | solana | rpc port: {rpc_port} is already in use

Tags: solana, anchor-solana

I am trying to install anchor-cli in mac os. I followed [this guide](https://project-serum.github.io/anchor/getting-started/installation.html#install-anchor) to install anchor-cli. But I am getting the following error while executing the `cargo install --git https://github.com/project-serum/anchor --tag v0.24.2 anchor-cli --locked` command

```
   Compiling anchor-cli v0.24.2 (/Users/selvam/.cargo/git/checkouts/anchor-bf03d42499b9267c/0b4c7b0/cli)
error: there is no argument named `rpc_port`
    --> cli/src/lib.rs:2211:40
     |
2211 |             "Your configured rpc port: {rpc_port} is already in use"
     |                                        ^^^^^^^^^^

error: there is no argument named `faucet_port`
    --> cli/src/lib.rs:2221:43
     |
2221 |             "Your configured faucet port: {faucet_port} is already in use"
     |                                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^

error: could not compile `anchor-cli` due to 2 previous errors
warning: build failed, waiting for other jobs to finish...
error: failed to compile `anchor-cli v0.24.2 (https://github.com/project-serum/anchor?tag=v0.24.2#0b4c7b0c)`, intermediate artifacts can be found at `/var/folders/pr/mfnrnlh92974pfszrqmj3l940000gp/T/cargo-installAhWbj9`
```

solana --version
solana-cli 1.9.0 (src:7782d34b; feat:378846963)

rustup --version
rustup 1.23.1 (3df2264a9 2020-11-30)
info: This is the version for the rustup toolchain manager, not the rustc compiler.
info: The currently active `rustc` version is `rustc 1.56.1 (59eed8a2a 2021-11-01)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your rust version is outdated.
Try again after upgrading rust version.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: What version is working actually?

Comment: I am now using:
`rustc 1.61.0 (fe5b13d68 2022-05-18)
rustup 1.24.3 (ce5817a94 2021-05-31)`